# ERRNO: 2 Division by zero error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error : 
ERRNO: 2
TEXT: Division by zero
LOCATION: C:\xampp\htdocs\final\classes\customer.php, line 183, at April 2, 2010, 3:49 pm

I have the following function in my class Customer

```
public static function GetQuotationDetails($string)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT I.name, I.discounted_price, I.other_name
                FROM item I
                WHERE ( I.name LIKE CONCAT(  '%', :string,  '%' )) ---line 183
                AND T.item_name=:string';
        $parameters = array(':string' => $string);
        DB::GetAll($sql,$parameters);



    }
```

Then,

```
$this->results = Customer::GetQuotationDetails('grinder');
```

and i echo the results by

```
echo $obj_quotations->results;
```

Can anyone help me?
When i run the sql code and replace :string by 'grinder', it displays the required records.

Comment: `Can anyone help me?`: not really, you haven't specified where the error occurs and your code has no divisions at all, so most likely you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: I have posted all relevant codes above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax highlighting in your question is a dead give-away. The `%` signs aren't treated as part of the string. They are actually trying to compute the remainder of dividing two strings.

You need to escape the single-quotes in the SQL statement, thus:

```
...LIKE CONCAT(  \'%\', :string,  \'%\' ))
```

Or (my preference) use a double-quoted string for the statement so that the single-quotes aren't treated as special.

Comment: Yes, if a string contains single quotes, it is common practice to delimit the string with double quotes to increase code readability.